# How to allow .ged file uploads

Tags: uploads

I am trying to allow gedcom file uploads. These files have a .ged extension.

Gedcom files do not have a mime type.

I have tried the following code with various text/types such as csv, rtf etc without success.

```
    function my_mime_types($mime_types){
$mime_types['ged'] = 'text/csv';
    return $mime_types;}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'my_mime_types', 1, 1);
```

Any suggestions as to how to add this type of file extension to the permitted uploads?

Answer (score 0):

you **need to allow them** to be uploaded in your media files.

you can add following code to your themes functions.php and it should work.

```
function my_mime_types($mime_types){
    $mime_types['ged'] = 'application/octet-stream';
    return $mime_types;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'my_mime_types', 1, 1);
```

there is more information about **adding new mime types in WP** here: https://wpsmackdown.com/add-remove-filetypes-wordpress-media-library/#add-filetypes

Here is an info about the .ged File MIME Type: https://whatis.techtarget.com/fileformat/GED-Genealogical-data-GEDCOM

And here a list of the **mime_types**: https://feedforall.com/mime-types.htm

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that doesn't work, Wordpress still says not an allowed file type. Thanks also for the links I was aware of those as I researched before asking the question.

Comment: hmm.. then i'm sorry. i think it might be still the wrong MIME type. just read something here http://www.gedcomx.org/2013/06/19/gedcomx-media-types.html with `application/x-gedcomx-v1+xml` or `application/x-gedcomx-v1+json`

Comment: Thanks but gedcomx is a totally different format being XML. Gedcom is just standard txt.

Answer (score 0):

I have now resolved this by changing the type to text/plain so the code now looks like:

```
function my_mime_types($mime_types){
$mime_types['ged'] = 'text/plain';
return $mime_types;}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'my_mime_types', 1, 1);
```

It seems that a security patch in v5.0.1 and v4.9.9 has tightened up the mime type of uploads and the checking of the file types.